# Передача данных из Activity во фрагменты, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

появилась проблема нужно передать параметр из Activity в Фрагмент что уже только не пытался делать и гуглил в инете но там всё по Яве и в Kotlin увы не удалось переделать, поэтому прошу вашей помощи, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать на Kotlin.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача данных из Activity в Fragment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640916/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-activity-%d0%b2-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я за месяц третий раз отвечаю на это вопрос на SO, так что с уверенностью заявляю - недостаточно гуглили :)

Передать параметр из Activity во Fragment можно двумя способами

1. При создании фрагмента передать ему в свойство arguments объект класса Bundle, содержащий все нужные параметры. Но так можно передать только примитивы и строки
2. Создать во фрагменте сеттер и отдавать через него объект. В общем-то, первый способ это тоже передача объекта через сеттер, но кто создателям фрагментов судья? Но аргументы вроде сохраняются даже без retainState

если в обратную сторону, то смотрите мой ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979104/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-fragment-activity-fragment/979399#979399)

Comment: Первый случай правильнее будет :) Сложные данные фрагмент должен уметь сам получить.